# How to SFINAE out non-containers parameters

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, sfinae

I have a template function that I want to enable only for standard containers (or containers compatible with standard containers, which at least provide a `begin()` member function). I'm SFINAE-ing out non-containers in the following way:

```
template<typename Container>
typename Container::value_type 
f(const Container& c,
    typename std::enable_if<
        std::is_same<
            decltype(*c.begin()),
            typename Container::value_type
        >::value
    >::type* = nullptr)
{
    // implementation here
}
```

The `std::is_same` and `decltype` don't look too elegant. Is there any better way of doing this?

PS: I need the SFINAE here because I have a different overload

```
template<typename Derived>
f(const Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>& A)
```

and whenever I try `f(some_Eigen_matrix)`, the `Container` overload ends up being picked up, then the compiler spits out an error because the type is lacking `begin()`.

Comment: Why are you doing the equality check, anyway? Doesn't it suffice if the expression is valid?

Comment: `auto f(const Container &c) -> decltype(c.begin(), (void) c.end())`

Comment: Ok, it's a bit more messy. The return type is a sum over the elements of the container.

Comment: Might make more sense to write a trait to see if something derives from `MatrixBase`, and then tag dispatch on that.

Comment: @T.C. that's almost impossible, since `MatrixBase<Derived>` is in general an expression template, so I cannot use the comma operator with different types.

Comment: I'm trying to understand your objections...and failing miserably. Care to elaborate?

Comment: @T.C. `template<class Derived> Eigen::MatrixBase< Derived >` is a template base class. In general, an expression `A+B` is of some type `Eigen::MatrixBase<Matrix_Sum>`, whereas something like `A*B` is of type `Eigen::MatrixBase<Matrix_Product>` (and this generalizes when we have more complicated things like e.g. `A+B*C`). There is no relationship between these `MatrixBase` instantiations.

Comment: @vsoftco But you can check that it is a `MatrixBase<T>` for some `T`, not a *specific* `T`

Comment: @Barry How do you do that? Will `is_same<Container, MatrixBase<T>` work with generic `T`?

Comment: @vsoftco `template <typename T> is_matrix : false_type { }; template <typename T> is_matrix<MatrixBase<T>> : true_type { };` ?

Comment: @Barry thanks, I have to look more into templates. Of course it works :)

Comment: @vsoftco http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30202552/template-method-matching-derived-type-instead-of-base/30203283#30203283

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using [`void_t`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3911), we can just make a type trait for having `begin()` and `end()` (and anything else you might want to check for, like `typename T::iterator`, you can just keep piling expressions on):

```
template <typename T, typename = void>
struct is_std_container : std::false_type { };

template <typename T>
struct is_std_container<T,
    void_t<decltype(std::declval<T&>().begin()),
           decltype(std::declval<T&>().end()),
           typename T::value_type
           >>
    : std::true_type { };
```

And then just SFINAE on that:

```
template <typename Container>
typename std::enable_if<
    is_std_container<Container>::value,
    typename Container::value_type
>::type 
f(const Container& c) { .. }
```

Also, if you really wanted to verify that `begin()` gives you back a `T::iterator` (or at least that they're equality comparable), you can do that too:

```
void_t<
    decltype(begin(std::declval<T&>()) == std::declval<typename T::iterator>())
>
```

Comment: Yes, this indeed looks better, and I'll probably go this way, since I am re-using this check. Thanks!

Comment: The `void_t` trick seems very neat, thanks for the link to the paper.

Comment: The only thing it escapes me is why the `is_std_container<Container>` will pick up the `true_type` specialization when `Container` is indeed a container? Sorry if the question seem silly. I actually found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27687389/how-does-void-t-work, will read it. I think the idea is that a matchin partial specialization is always better. CLEVER!