# C++ test for containers via SFINAE

Tags: c++, templates, stl, c++17, sfinae

In C++17, I'm trying to detect containers (maps) by checking for the presence of `value_type` (`mapped_type`). However, while it seems to work for `unordered_set<int>` it fails for `unordered_set<int*>` which I find weird. Can you tell me why and how to do it properly?

```c++
  template<class N, class T = int>
  struct is_container { static const bool value = false; };
  template<class N>
  struct is_container<N, typename N::value_type> { static const bool value = true; };
  template<class N>
  static constexpr bool is_container_v = is_container<remove_reference_t<N>>::value;


int main()
{
  cout << is_container_v<unordered_set<int>&> << '\n';
  cout << is_container_v<unordered_set<int*>&> << '\n';
}
```

output:

```
1
0
```

PS: I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30244447/how-to-sfinae-out-non-containers-parameters) which filters by presence of `begin()` but that doesn't help telling a `map` from `set`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keeping  your test, it should be

```
template<class N, class Enabler = void>
struct is_container { static const bool value = false; };

template<class N>
struct is_container<N, std::void_t<typename N::value_type>>
{ static const bool value = true; };

template<class N>
static constexpr bool is_container_v = is_container<remove_reference_t<N>>::value;
```

As, with your version

`is_container_v<unordered_set<int*>&>` is `is_container<unordered_set<int*>>` and with default: `is_container<unordered_set<int*>, int>`

whereas you specialize for `is_container<unordered_set<int*>, int*>`...

Comment: ah, thanks for the explanation, that makes perfect sense now. I had a misunderstanding about specializations...